# How to find out root cause of transaction failure in Firestore?

Tags: java, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

If a Firestore transaction fails, it throws `FirestoreException` which only says **"Transaction was cancelled because of too many retries."**

There is no root cause or any other clue, even if I set the number of retires to 1.

Is it possible to get the root cause?

Comment: This typically happens because the data you're trying to modify is being modified by some other client/process while the transaction is running. If that happens the Firestore client will retry the transaction. But if it happens repeatedly, it gives up. There is no way to get more information beyond that.

Comment: Firestore doesn't have a way to set the number of retries for a transaction.  What are you actually setting in this case?

Comment: @DougStevenson it does, at least in Java Admin SDK.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. Sorry if I wasn't clear, I am not looking to debug a particular case but rather to be able to programmatically determine the root cause (at least the most obvious ones, e.g. document too large)

Comment: Frank pointed out that the level of parallelism from all clients transacting on the same documents is the culprit.  Without understand the the actual transactions you're performing, and the level of parallelism, there's not much else to say.

Comment: Actually, in my case the problem was that the document was too large (over 1MB). 

I'm looking to programmatically be able to tell apart these causes, so that I can handle them properly.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/unity/class/firebase/firestore/firestore-exception) a [`FirestoreException`](https://github.com/googleapis/java-firestore/blob/master/google-cloud-firestore/src/main/java/com/google/cloud/firestore/FirestoreException.java) with the message "*Transaction was cancelled because of too many retries.*" can only be found under `private void runTransactionAttempt`:

```
 private void maybeRetry() {
            if (attemptsRemaining > 0) {
              span.addAnnotation("retrying");
              runTransactionAttempt(
                  transactionCallback,
                  resultFuture,
                  new TransactionOptions(
                      attemptsRemaining, options.getExecutor(), transaction.getTransactionId()),
                  span);
            } else {
              span.setStatus(TOO_MANY_RETRIES_STATUS);
              rejectTransaction(
                  FirestoreException.serverRejected(
                      Status.ABORTED, "Transaction was cancelled because of too many retries."));
            }
          }
```

As you can see - you faced repetitive exceptions when trying to run a transaction and/or batched write. After taking a look at the [Firebase documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions#java_3) you can see **three** main reasons to why a transaction might fail:

> **1.** The transaction contains read operations after write operations. Read
> operations must always come before any write operations.
>
> **2.** The transaction read a document that was modified outside of the
> transaction. In this case, the transaction automatically runs again.
>
> **3.** The transaction is retried a finite number of times. The transaction
> exceeded the maximum request size of 10 MiB.
> *Transaction size depends on the sizes of documents and index entries
> modified by the transaction. For a delete operation, this includes the
> size of the target document and the sizes of the index entries deleted
> in response to the operation.*

To debug the problem I highly suggest the following sources for **further reading** - *without a code snippet from your part it's hard to help you implement a solutio:*

- https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/monitor-usage
- https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/reporting-errors
- https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/writing-and-viewing-logs

Comment: Is there a way to log the GRPC ApiException? perhaps the status code there would help narrow down which of these is the actual issue.

Comment: @Andrew Do you mean generally or in the case of OP?

Comment: @Andrew One can only catch what is being thrown (or set a break-point).

Comment: @MartinZeitler Correct - though in the case of the original question it actually was due to extending the upload limit (as he himself has mentioned). That’s why I asked specifically, but thanks for for your reply!

Answer (score -1):

You should check your firebase console firestore rules, if edit is allowed... create new, edit permissions.

```
service cloud.firestore {  
    match /databases/{database}/documents {
        // Anyone can read a product, only authorized
        // users can create or update. Deletes are not allowed.
        match /products/{productId} {
            allow read: if true;
            allow create, update: if request.auth.uid != null;
        }
    }
}
```